# Rearranging javascript array / object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I'm trying to re-arrange:

```
[
    {"Appointment":"6","Converted":"0","Lead":"9","Qualified":"0","Dead":"0"},
    {"Appointment":"1","Converted":"0","Lead":"1","Qualified":"0","Dead":"0"},
    {"Appointment":"1","Converted":"0","Lead":"0","Qualified":"0","Dead":"0"}
]
```

To:

```
[
    {"name":"Appointment", "data":[6,1,1]},
    {"name":"Converted", "data":[0,0,0]},
    {"name":"Lead", "data":[9,1,0]},
    {"name":"Qualified", "data":[0,0,0]},
    {"name":"Dead", "data":[0,0,0]}
]
```

I've managed to get the 5 array's with the correct name in, by doing for(var prop in obj) loop, but I'm wondering how to achieve converting the data part.  Wishful thinking perhaps, but is there an easier way than looping within loops!?

The solution would have to be dynamic... there could be 3 arrays like in my example or more or less.  The number of properties will always by 5 however, as is in the example.

Comment: Is the number of categories fixed? Five in your case

Comment: Good point, I've edited my question, thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't use an array as the result. It would be easier if you used an object whose keys were the names, e.g. `{"Appointment": [6,1,1], "Converted": [0,0,0], ...}`

Comment: Unfortunately the result has to be in the format shown, as it's going to be used in a HighChart graph...

Comment: do you need the Number numbers? (an easy diff to overlook in before+after pairing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the keys in object then put in array... like in the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/u7xLnmuh/

```
var data = [
    {"Appointment":"6","Converted":"0","Lead":"9","Qualified":"0","Dead":"0"},
    {"Appointment":"1","Converted":"0","Lead":"1","Qualified":"0","Dead":"0"},
    {"Appointment":"1","Converted":"0","Lead":"0","Qualified":"0","Dead":"0"}
]


function groupByKey(data){
    var grouped = {};
    var result = [];

    data.forEach(function(row){

        for(var property in row){

            if(!(property in grouped)){
                grouped[property] = [];
            }

            grouped[property].push(+row[property]);            
        }        
    });

    for(var property in grouped){
        result.push({
            name: property,
            data: grouped[property]
        });
    }

    return result;

}


var groupedData = groupByKey(data));
```

this solution is generic to any set of data inputted

Comment: Great thanks, perfect.  Both answers correct, but you got there first and the data result was an integer and not a string, thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

Make the result be an object whose keys are the names, because it's easier to look this up:

```
var result = {};
for (var key in input[0]) {
    result[key] = [];
}
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var obj = input[i];
    for (key in obj) {
        result[key].push(parseInt(obj[key], 10));
    }
}
```

If you really need the results as an array of objects, you can then convert `result`:

```
var result_array = [];
for (var name in result) {
    result_array.push({name: name, data: result[name]});
}
```

Comment: There is no foreach in JS

Comment: might also cleanup the newly-added implicit global for good measure, since other apps sometimes depend on the pre-defined _window.name_...

Comment: i would add result[name].map(Number) to comply with OP's desired output, but usually type doesn't matter so it may be fine for the charting...

Comment: I didn't even notice that the input numbers were strings, I've added `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to parseInt() on this to no avail... clearly I have a lot left to learn in JS.  this was the key for me in solving this problem: result_array.push({name: name, data: result[name]});